# Green's Theorem with change of variables

Tags: integration, greens-theorem

Evaluate $$\int_C F dr$$
$$ F =< x2, xy > $$
$$ C: x^2/4^2 + y^2/9 = 1 $$

With y ≥ 0 positively oriented.

---

For the circle

$$ u^2 + v^2 = 1 $$

$$ u=x/a $$

$$ v=y/b $$

$$ x=au $$

$$ y=bv $$

For the ellipse

$$ (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1 $$

Computing the jacobian, I get 6. So, using greens theorem and switching to polar I get:

$$ \int \int (6rsinθ) rdrdθ $$

Just want someone to see if I've completed the changing of variables correctly. Computing integrals isn't all that difficult but I'm having a bit of trouble with the setup still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F=(F_1(x,y),F_2(x,y))=(x^2,xy)$$
$$\oint\limits_{C}{F.dr}=\int{\int{\left( \frac{\partial {{F}_{2}}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial {{F}_{1}}}{\partial y} \right)}}\,dA=\int\int y\,dA$$
let $x=2r\cos\theta$ and $y=3r\sin\theta$ we have 
$$\left| \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta )} \right|=6r$$
and
$$\int\limits_{C}{F.dr}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{1}} 18r^2\sin\theta\,drd\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin \theta d\theta\times\int_{0}^{1}18r^2dr=0$$

Comment: I got the same answer to the integral. Your setup is way faster though!

Comment: Please ,your solution is correct. good luck

Comment: how do you get x=2rcos and y=3rsin ?

Comment: $a=\sqrt{4}$ and $b=\sqrt{9}$ and $dxdy=a\,b\,r\,drd\theta$

Comment: How come we write x=2rcos and y=3rsin. I can see where the 2 and 3 come from, they are the radius of the ellipse with respect to an axis, but why do we include the r in the equations?

Comment: It is famous Changing problem